# raspberry pi 2 raspicam auto start problem

Tags: python

I write a python program opencv and python. also I'm using raspicam and I want using my python program without keyboard and mouse. Of course auto run mode. I tried two ways like below and I can't find solution.

1. `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
   between codes and exit0 I write `sudo python /home/pi/my_program.py` or `sudo python /home/pi/my_program.py &` 
   then ctrl+x , Y, enter. after reboot, raspicam blink on and a few second later blink off.
2. `sudo crontab -e`
   and then I write `@reboot python /home/pi/my_program.py` or `@reboot python /home/pi/my_program.py &`
   then ctrl+x , Y, enter. after reboot, raspicam blink on and a few second later blink off.

I tried two way and I couldn't do it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your script works fine when invoked manually on terminal. Well, does your program make use of GUI functions like imshow or something ? If that's the case, you can't invoke it using rc.local / crontab since items in both of them execute before running an X server.

You will have to place it under /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart.

Follow these steps :

1. sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
2. Add this line at the end : @sudo /usr/bin/python /path/to/script/script-name.py
3. Ctrl + x, yes to save changes.
4. Reboot to make it effective.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the answer from dhruvvyas90 got me on the right track, but the autostart file in question wasn't actually launching anything.

Based on this forum here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=131760 I found that replacing the first step with

```
nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Was what I needed.